# Why type conversion between int and float causes data loss?

Tags: c, gcc

In the following program type conversion of pointers from int to float and from floar to int is done but the output is not correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a, *ptr_i, *ptr_xi;
float f, *ptr_f, *ptr_xf;

a = 65;
f = 65.5;

ptr_i = &a;
ptr_f = &f;
ptr_xi = ptr_i;
ptr_xf = ptr_f;

ptr_f = (float*) ptr_xi;
ptr_i = (int*) ptr_xf;
            
printf("The value of \"ptr_i\" is %d\n", *ptr_i);
printf("The value of \"ptr_f\" is %f\n", *ptr_f);

return 0;
}
```

The value of "ptr_i" is 1115881472

The value of "ptr_f" is 0.000000

This type of type cast conversion is possible with variables and shown in the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a, i;
float b, f;

a = 65;
b = 65.5;

f = (float) a;
i = (int) b;

printf("The value of 'i' is %d\n", i);
printf("The value of 'f' is %.2f\n", f);

return 0;
}
```

Output:

The value of 'i' is 65

The value of 'f' is 65.00

But why this output is not seen when type casting is used with pointers?

Comment: remove `C++` or `C` tag, they are different languages. (e.g. in C++ you would use `static_cast<float>(a)` not `(float)a`). And in C++ the use of pointers should be limited.

Comment: Casting pointers from on type to another and hoping things go right when dereferencing is just incorrect code.

Comment: Because what you are converting are the pointers, not what is being pointed at. You start with a pointer that is pointing at a valid `float`, you tell the compiler that it is actually pointing at a valid `int`. Of course this is a lie, so it's not surprising that the results are unpredictable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Assignments of pointers do not break the aliasing rules. Conversions between pointers to object types with the same alignment requirements are defined by the C standard. Dereferencing pointers is where the aliasing rules apply. Specifically, they apply to accessing objects with lvalues.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're right, the assignment itself doesn't break strict aliasing. But after that assignment, would `*ptr_f` break it?

Comment: In addition to strict aliasing violations on dereference, merely assigning a `float *` from an `int *` pointer can violate alignment restrictions and invoke undefined behavior.  Per [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, p7 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7):  "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. ..."

Comment: `(float*) ptr_xi` says "pretend that `ptr_xi` points at a float". In the real world it doesn't.

Comment: Evaluating `*ptr_i` and `*ptr_f` in the first sample causes undefined behaviour, since (with the help of type casts) both pointers point at an actual object of different type   (to dereference a pointer, the actual type of the pointee and the type of what the pointer points at must be compatible).   In the second sample, the casts convert numeric values to the required type (`(float)a` converts the value `a` (`65`) to a `float` (`65.0f`), etc).

Comment: There is no "data loss". The data are unchanged; you are printing them incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

`*ptr_i` says to interpret the bytes that `ptr_i` is pointing to as if they were an `int`. However, the bytes were stored using the encoding scheme for `float`. The C standard does not define what happens when you say to reinterpret bytes this way. However, many C implementations perform the reinterpretation. This can vary depending on optimization level, circumstances of the surrounding program, compiler switches, and other factors.

Similarly, `*ptr_f` says to interpret the bytes that `ptr_f` points to as if they were `float`, but those bytes were stored using the encoding scheme for `int`.

65.5 in binary is 1000001.1<sub>2</sub>. In the format commonly used for `float`, this is encoded using one bit for a sign, eight bits to encode an exponent and information about the significand.<sup>1</sup>, and 23 bits for the trailing bits of the significand. For 65.5:

- The sign is positive, which is encoded as 0.
- The exponent is 6 (1000001.1<sub>2</sub> is scaled to be 1.0000011<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>6</sup>, to normalize the significand to have one digit before the “.”). The exponent is encoded by adding a fixed amount 127, so the code is 133 = 10000101.
- The trailing bits of the significand (the bits after “.”) are 00000110000000000000000.

So 65.5 is encoded as 0 10000101 00000110000000000000000<sub>2</sub>, which is 1,115,881,472 in decimal.

Going the other way, 65 in binary is 1000001<sub>2</sub> = 0000000000000000000001000001<sub>2</sub>. When interpreted in the `float` format:

- The first bit is 0, meaning positive.
- The eight exponent field bits are 00000000<sub>2</sub>. This is a special code that means the number is subnormal, which means the leading bit of its significand will be 0 instead of 1 and the exponent will be the low limit, −126.
- The trailing significand bits are 00000000000000001000001<sub>2</sub>.

This means the bits encode a value of +0.00000000000000001000001<sub>2</sub>•2<sup>−126</sup>, which is approximately 9.10844•10<sup>−44</sup>. When this is converted to a string with `%f`, it is too small to affect any of the digits so the result is “0.000000”.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The significand is the fraction of a floating-point representation. When 3137 is represented as 3.137•103, the significand is 3.137.

Answer (score 0):

There is no data loss, you are just doing something you do not want to do.

By saying

```
int a = 65;
int *ptr_i = &a;
float *ptr_f = (float*) ptr_i;
```

you make the system believe that `*ptr_f` (on many systems 4 bytes of storage) should be interpreted as a float (IEEE 754 floating point semantics). But you initialized the four bytes it points to with the *integer* 65, (which stores the 4 bytes 0x000000A1). If you interpret these with the floating point standard, it basically means the value is 0.0 multiplied with a "random"-seeming number that comes from the A1 bytes. Effectively, that means the bytes are 0.0 when interpreted as a float.

Your second example behaves differently because it does something very different. It actually assigns `float f = (float) a;`. This is the very same as `float f = a;` and as the compiler knows that `a` is an integer, it will convert the value to the float format for you when it writes the value to `f`.
As the assignment in the first is to assign the pointer variable `ptr_f` instead, the compiler will not without your knowledge touch the bytes it points to to convert them (and it really shouldn't).